# Processing 3 - Android Mode - Blank window "Cannot find an Android SDK"

Tags: java, android, processing

I've installed android studio and processing 3, and I can't use Android mode. I can't select anything in this blank window and can't close it. Any fixes? You to use Android Mode?

Distro: Arch

Processing - 3.5 linuxX64

[image: Just blank screen]

Answer (score 0):

I did face the same problem using Processing 3 in Ubuntu 16.04 .
The problem solved when I added the following lines in `/home/<username>/.processing/preferences.txt`

```
android.emulator.image.abi=x86
android.sdk.gvr=1.150.0
android.sdk.path=/home/<username>/sketchbook/android/sdk
android.sdk.play_services=11.0.4
android.sdk.support=26.0.2
android.sdk.target=26
android.sdk.wear=2.1.0
```

Then, I ran Processing 3 and I chose Android from the list.
This time, the window about the android sdk appeared with text.

PS. I had **not** created the android.sdk.path prior the installation.

Answer (score 0):

I came across that issue and solve it. But if u do that you may be lost all sketches. Firstly, remove /home//.processing/ and /home//sketchbook. Than execute `./uninstall.sh` which is your installation folder.(for me /opt/processing-3.5.3 ). than install 3.4 version from [processing download page](https://processing.org/download/) . Than extract it where you want and  execute `./install.sh`. Open processing IDE. Check version it should be 3.4. Than install android mode it will be ask for sdk and download manually. Than go 3.4 version installation folder execute `./uninstall.sh` than install 3.5.5 version. It works for me.